# Using confusion matrix to find model accuracy instead of built-it predict method

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix

I have a dataset that I want to build a classification model for it. Given that `scikit-learn` provides confusion matrix implementation `confusion_matrix(test_y, pred_r)`, I want to use it to calculate the accuracy of my model instead of directly using `.predict`. To do so, should I just look for `false positive` or `true positive` or the combination of both?

Thank you

Comment: You can use the `.score()` method of the estimator instead of predict. Also, inbuilt `accuracy_score()` is also there which can calculate accuracy from `test_y` and  `pred_r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding the accuracy, just do this:

```
accuracy = (TP + TN)/Total
```

Comment: Thank you very much. `Total` here is the total samples in the dataset or just in the `test` dataset ( I use train_test_split)?

Comment: Total is the number of samples in the dataset on which you are doing the confusion matrix. It can be training set or the validation set. The number of samples changes accordingly